# Get Single based on return value of Flowable and merge result

Tags: rx-java2

I have a call to a method which returns a `Flowable<List<Entity>>`. For every Entity in this list I want to call a method which returns the associated `Single<AnotherEntity>`. `Entity` and `AnotherEntity` should then be merged into a single object and all of them should be returned in a list.

What I have right now looks like this:

```
return playerRepository.getAllPlayers()
    .flatMapIterable(players -> players)
   .map(player -> player.apiId)
   .flatMapSingle(apiId -> statsRepository.getGameLog(apiId))
   .subscribe(
           stats -> { statsEntries.add(stats); }
   );
```

How can i change this into a clean solution which fulfills my requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need that intermediate `map()` and you can map the result of the second map into a pair that contains the original Entity:

```
return playerRepository.getAllPlayers()
    .flatMapIterable(players -> players)
    .flatMapSingle(player -> 
        statsRepository.getGameLog(player.apiId)
        .map(log -> new BothEntities(player, log))
    )
    .toList()
    .subscribe(
        allEntities -> { /* handle the list */ }
    );
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work at first because the `Flowable` never completes. After changing it to a `Single` this solution now does exactly what i want.

Comment: You have to be careful with certain datasources because their Flowables are usually reporting live updates that never end.